# Is $2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + ... = -\frac12$ or $-1$?

Tags: divergent-series, regularization

Using [zeta function regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization), the divergent series [$1+1+1+1+...$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) can be evaluated to yield $$1+1+1+1+1+...=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^0}=\zeta(0)=-\frac12.$$

But what is $2+2+2+2+...$ then? On the one hand, it should be twice as much, but on the other hand each $2=1+1$ so it could also be $-\frac12$ again. My gut feeling is that factoring out the $2$ of this divergent series is formally "less" valid than expanding the twos into sums of ones, but is the a sensible non-ambiguous answer?

Comment: You may find [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/) read useful.

Comment: You wrote: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n^0}=\zeta(0)=-\frac12$. This is wrong. If you start from $n=0$, the sum is $\zeta(1)=1/2$. If you start from $n=1$, the sum is $-1/2$.

Comment: @Anixx Fixed, thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ans: $-1$

Any linear summation method should have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nk=k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$.

A regular linear stable summation method need not give the same answer when $2$ is rewritten as $1+1$ for infinitely many of the $2$s, considering that infinitely permuting terms in diverging series can alter the sum, and that in $1+2+4+8+...=-1$, setting $2=1+1, 4=1+1+1+1$ etc. would make the sum $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: (+1). Plus: one should perhaps ***enhance*** the "infinitely" in the partial sentence "...for infinitely many of the 2s..." because this is exactly the point and one should explicitely focus on this. *(Just an opinion)*

Comment: That makes perfectly sense, thanks for the more intuitive $1+2+4+8+... \neq 1 + (1+1) + (1+1+1+1) + ...$ example

Comment: "Any linear summation method *should* have"...so is the property not part of the definition of "linear" here?

Comment: The last paragraph is a little bit misleading, because no *stable* method can sum the series $2+2+2+2+\cdots$ or $1+1+1+1+\cdots$ at all. A more direct example of the same argument would be the series $1-1+1-1+\cdots$, whose Cesaro sum is $1/2$, versus the "rewritten" version $1+0-1+1+0-1+\cdots$, whose Cesaro sum is $2/3$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter: or grouped as $(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\dots=0$. Regularization is very sensitive to rearrangement.

Comment: There are arguments that 2+2+2+2+2... = 0, actually...

Comment: You wrote: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n^0}=\zeta(0)=-\frac12$. This is wrong. If you start from $n=0$, the sum is $\zeta(1)=1/2$. If you start from $n=1$, the sum is $-1/2$. If you do not specify from where you start and write $1+2+3+4+...$, the answer can be any.

Answer (score 0):

This claim is wrong:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n^0}=-\frac12$$

These equalities are correct:

$$\operatorname{reg}\sum_{n=0}^\infty1=\frac12$$

$$\operatorname{reg}\sum_{n=1}^\infty1=-\frac12$$

You can check them in Wolfram Mathematica.

```
Sum[1,{n,0,Infinity},Regularization->Dirichlet]
Sum[1,{n,1,Infinity},Regularization->Dirichlet]
```

So,

$$\operatorname{reg}\sum_{n=0}^\infty2=2\operatorname{reg}\sum_{n=0}^\infty1=1$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but "Mathematica says so" is not really convincing

Comment: Yet this downvoted answer was correct, and the given answer is incorrect. The statement in the question about zeta(0) is false, because as this answer pointed out he starts the sum at 0 and not 1.

Comment: @Gerben Oh, my bad, I didn't read this answer as "you accidentally started the sum at $n=0$ instead of 1." Sorry!