# Something strange about expectation of geometric variable

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose I toss a fair coin independently until I get a tail. Let X be the number of time the coin is tossed, if the coin is tossed x times, a reward of $2^x$ will be given, the question is what is the expected money I get?

A systematic approach would be to think of X is a geometric random variables and let $g(x)=2^x$ then use the formula

$E[g(x)]=\sum_xg(x)P_X(x)=\sum_x1$

which can not even be evaluated.
Can anyone tell me where I was wrong?

Comment: Actually, you receive either 2 or 4 or... $2^x$ or... dollars hence I fail to understand how the mean of these could be 1 dollar, intuitively or not. Clearly the mean amount of money you receive is **greater** than 2 dollars.

Comment: Right! But what about the above approach, is it correct?

Comment: The expected value of $g(X)$ can be evaluated, it is $+\infty$.

Comment: @Augustin Sooo tempted to say ["No, it's $-\frac{1}{2}$"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468839/is-2-2-2-2-frac12-or-1?s=18|0.6152) ;)

Comment: @lplouis Yes, it is correct until $E(g(X))=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 1$... and then the RHS can be evaluated and its value is $+\infty$.

Comment: You may want to read about the [St. Petersburg lottery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach leading to the same result.

$2^X$ is nonnegative so at forehand we know that $0\leq\mathbb E2^X\leq+\infty$.

Let $T$ denote the event that the first toss gives a tail and $H$
the event that the first toss gives a head.

$\mathbb{E}2^{X}=\mathbb{E}\left(2^{X}\mid T\right)P\left(T\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(2^{X}\mid H\right)P\left(H\right)=2^{1}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{E}2^{X+1}.\frac{1}{2}=1+\mathbb{E}2^{X}$

This can only be true if $\mathbb{E}2^{X}=+\infty$.