# Find the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+xy+y^2)} \, dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Given that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx=\sqrt{\pi}$. Find the value of $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+xy+y^2)} \, dx\,dy$$

I don't understand how I find this double integral by using the given data. Please help.

Comment: Hints: (i) use a change of variables to find the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x+a)^2}\,dx$.  (ii) write $x^2 + xy + y^2$ as $(x+y/2)^2 + 3y^2/4$ and then use the answer of (i) while doing the inner integral.

Comment: A more general version of the integral:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653159/if-a-is-positive-definite-then-int-mathbbrn-mathrme-langle-ax-x?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+xy+y^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-((x+y/2)^2+3y^2/4)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(u^2+3y^2/4)}\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-3y^2/4}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u
\sqrt{\frac43}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-v^2}\,\mathrm{d}v\\
&=\sqrt\pi\sqrt{\frac43}\sqrt\pi\\
&=\pi\sqrt{\frac43}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 13):

For fun, I want to point out that much more can be said. The [spectral theorem for real symmetric matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Properties) tells us that real symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable. Thus, if $A$ is some symmetric matrix, then there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ and diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A$ can be written as $A=U^{-1} DU$. Hence $x^TAx=x^TU^TDUx=(Ux)^TD(Ux)$. The Jacobian det of the transformation $x\mapsto Ux$ is simply $1$, so we have a change of variables $u=Ux$:

$$\begin{align} \int_{{\bf R}^n}\exp\left(-x^TAx\right)\,dV & =\int_{{\bf R}^n}\exp\left(-(\lambda_1u_1^2+\cdots+\lambda_nu_n^2)\right)\,dV \\[6pt]
& =\prod_{i=1}^n\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\lambda_i u_i^2\right)du_i \\[6pt]
& =\prod_{i=1}^n\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2} \, du\right] \\[6pt]
& =\sqrt{\frac{\pi^n}{\det A}}.\end{align}$$

Note that we don't even have to compute $U$ or $D$. The above calculation is the generalized version of the "completing the squares" approach when $n=2$ (which is invoked elsewhere in this thread).

This formula is in fact the basis for the Feynman path integral formulation of the functional determinant from quantum field theory; since technically the integral diverges we need to compare them instead of looking at individual ones outright. [Wikipedia has some more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant).

Comment: Neat observation; certainly more insightful than my answer :-)

Comment: @robjohn Well, the observation clearly does not originate with me. What's even more amazing is the fact that Feynman path integrals and zeta regularization *agree with each other* on functional determinants (see link at the end of this answer). Why this is, though, is a mystery to me, and is the subject of [this question of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54592/why-do-zeta-regularization-and-path-integrals-agree-on-functional-determinants).

Comment: The reason your integral signs were so tiny and otherwise formatted as if they were inline rather than displayed is that you used "array" rather than "align". I edited.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate in polar coordinates

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+xy+y^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
=&\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^\infty e^{-r^2(1+\frac12\sin2\theta)}rdr d\theta
= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2+\sin2\theta}
=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}
\end{align}
$$