# How do I evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(3x^2+2 \sqrt 2 xy+3y^2)} \mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function, multiple-integral

> Evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-3x^2-2 \sqrt 2 xy - 3y^2\right) \, \mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

I first evaluate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[-3\bigl(x^2+ y^2\bigr)\right] \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

using polar coordinates, which evaluates to $\pi/3$. But I find difficulty to evaluate the double integral  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-2 \sqrt 2 xy\right) \, \mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$ Would anybody please help me finding it out?

Comment: Where are the limits of integration on $y$?

Comment: How can you separate this integral into those two integrals?  The integrand of the first integral is the *product* of the integrands of the latter two, not the *sum*.

Comment: Are you sure that what you want isn't $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(3x^2+2\sqrt2xy+3y^2)}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$?

Comment: Sorry I have corrected my problem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653159/if-a-is-positive-definite-then-int-mathbbrn-mathrme-langle-ax-x?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384732/find-the-value-of-int-infty-infty-int-infty-inftye-x2xyy2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$3x^2+2\sqrt{2} xy + 3y^2
=\begin{bmatrix}x & y \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & \sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{2} & 3 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$
so the integrand is
$$\exp(- v^\top \Omega v/2)$$
where $v = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ and $\Omega = 2\begin{bmatrix} 3 & \sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{2} & 3 \end{bmatrix}$.

By using the [density of a $N(0, \Sigma)$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function) we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^2 \det (\Omega^{-1})}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-v^\top \Omega v / 2) \, dx \, dy = 1.$$

Comment: fascinating . . . definitely learned something new

Comment: I've actually been studying this post and all the new concepts it's exposed me to. If the original integrand is $\exp\bigl(-v^\top\Omega v/2\bigr)$, then what allows $dv=d\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ to stand for $dx\,dy$, from the original differential?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor If you wish, you may write out $v$ as $(x,y)$ and write the integral as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \,dx \,dy$. I was just using some shorthand, but it is exactly the same as the original integral.

Comment: If one writes $v=xi+yj$ then $dv=dx\,i + dy\,j$, no? Which is different?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Doing the change of variables $x=X+Y$ and $y=X-Y$, your integral becomes$$2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left[-\left(2\sqrt2+6\right)X^2-\left(-2\sqrt2+6\right)Y^2\right]\,\mathrm dX\,\mathrm dY.$$