# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-xy+y^2)}dx\, dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-xy+y^2)}dx\, dy$$

I thought of evaluating the iterated integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-xy+y^2)}dy$, but because of the presence of $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms, I am not being able to do that. I tried substituting $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ but in that case I have some confusion regarding the limits of $r$ and $\theta$. Can I get some help?

Comment: This is odd, both strategies you mention actually work. What stopped you in each case?

Comment: In the first case I am not being able to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-xy+y^2)}dy$

Comment: Even after noting that $y^2-xy+x^2=(y-\frac12x)^2+\frac34x^2$ and using the change of variable $y=z+\frac12x$ to integrate on $y$?

Comment: oh yes... thats good .. So I think I can then reduce it to the form $e^{-z^2}$.. Ok lets try.

Comment: Let's, indeed... :-)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384732/find-the-value-of-int-infty-infty-int-infty-inftye-x2xyy2?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Recall:
$$x^2-xy+y^2=(x-\frac{1}{2}y)^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2$$
With that you get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-xy+y^2)}dxdy=\\\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left((x-\frac{1}{2}y)^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2\right)}dxdy=\\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x'^2+\frac{3}{4}y^2\right)}dx'dy=\\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}x'^2}dx'e^{-\frac{3}{8}y^2}dy=\\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-\frac{3}{8}y^2}dy=\\
\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}\pi}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\pi
$$

Answer (score 3):

The general gaussian integration formula is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ldots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac12 x^T Ax}dx_1\ldots dx_n=\frac{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\sqrt{\operatorname{det}A}}.$$
In your case, $n=2$ and $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1/2 \\ -1/2 & 1\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Completing the square is nothing else than diagonalizing $A$. After that you get a factor of $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a_i}}$ for each diagonal component $a_i$ on your diagonalized matrix. ($a_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$)

Comment: @Matthias Of course.