# Evaluate $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{−(19x^2+2xy+19y^2)}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate: $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{−(19x^2+2xy+19y^2)}\ dxdy$$

To be honest I am totally stuck and have no idea how to start. Any hint, help would be appreciable.

Comment: Could you do it if the $xy$ term were absent?

Comment: The quadratic form $19x^2+2xy+19y^2$ is positive definite, so the integral converges. Its matrix
$$A=\pmatrix{19&1\cr1&19\cr}$$ has determinant $19^2-1^2=360$. So the answer  is $\pi/\sqrt{360}$.

Comment: @jyrki I don't understand your arguement,it seems to me that I am missing some important information which you know,..can you please elaborate it a more

Comment: Is there any a priori which you used here?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/384732/321264 and its linked posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:**
$$
Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 = \alpha (x+\beta y)^2 + \gamma y^2,
$$

for some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.

**Hint 2:** If $\alpha,\gamma > 0$, you can use linear substitution to get $u^2+v^2$ in the exponent. Can you solve the integral with $u^2+v^2$?